# How to delete a specific number of random lines matching a pattern

Tags: regex, linux, bash, vim, sed

I have an svg file with a grid of dots represented by lines that have the word `use` in them. I would like to delete a specific number of random lines matching that `use` pattern, then save a new version of the file. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/163057) was very close.

So it will be a combination of this (delete one random line in a specific range):

```
sed -i '.svg' $((9 + RANDOM % 579))d /filename.svg
```

and this (delete all lines matching pattern `use`):

```
sed -i '.svg' /use/d /filename.svg
```

In other words, the logic would go something like this:

```
sed -i delete 'x' number of RANDOM lines matching 'use' from 'input.svg' and save to 'output.svg'
```

I'm running these commands from Terminal on a Mac and am inexperienced with syntax so formatting the command for that would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Delete each line containing "use" with a probability of 10%:

```
awk '!/use/ || rand() > 0.10' file
```

Randomly delete exactly one line containing "use":

```
awk -v n="$(( RANDOM % $(grep -c "use" file) ))" '!/use/ || n-- != 0' file
```

Here's an example invocation:

```
$ cat file
some string
a line containing "use"
another use-ful line
more random data

$ awk -v n="$(( RANDOM % $(grep -c "use" file) ))" '!/use/ || n-- != 0' file
some string
another use-ful line
more random data
```

One of the lines containing `use` was removed.

Comment: These seem to only be returning a giant list of all the lines containing 'use'

Comment: @substancejoy there was a typo in the latter one.

Comment: Hmm, now the second one prints the file in its entirety

Comment: @substancejoy I added an example run. Try copy-pasting it exactly and see if it still doesn't work (don't try to adapt it before you have tested it as is).

Comment: OK, that worked! The test prints exactly as expected, and it worked for the svg file as well. However, I need it modify the actual file or save a new copy of the file with the deleted lines. It also needs to remove a specific number of lines.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you: (GNU sed & sort):

```
sed -n '/\<use\>/=' file | sort -r | head -5 | sed 's/$/d/' | sed -i.bak -f - file
```

Extract the line numbers of the lines containing the word `use` from the file. Randomly sort those line numbers then take the first say 5 and build a sed script to delete them from the original file.